# Play and Pause external audio from my app?

Tags: android

I am currently making an application that uses the proximity sensor to play / pause and skip music.  If a hand is near for under a second, it plays and pauses, if it's over a second it will skip the song.  I have the "long" and "short" readouts measured properly, but I do not know how to play or pause music playing in another app from my app.  (Ex: Say a person is listening to YouTube Music, I need my app to be able to toggle the play state).

What lines of code would let me play or pause or skip songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about all apps. But this code works for some music app.

```
//Pause music
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.requestAudioFocus(null,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

//Play music 

am.abandonAudioFocus(null);
```